# Solving for time when the force has a complex solution?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, rotational-dynamics, integration

> A $1 kg$ particle exists in a 1-dimensional coordinate system. At time $t = 0$, the particle is at rest at $x = 0$ metres. It experiences a force (in Newtons) described by the following equation:
>
> $\large{F(x,t) = 3xt + 1}$
>
> At what time (in seconds) does the particle reach $x = 4 \, m$? Give your answer to 2 decimal places.

So I tried solving this equation by two methods.

1) By writing F as ma and a as $v \dfrac{dv}{dx}$. But then i realised that we cant integrate like that, as time on the RHS isnt constant. Even if I assume it to be constant, and then try to write v as dx/dt, the term on the right is such that x cant be seperated from t?

2) Writing a as $\dfrac{d^2x}{dt^2}$ but I am not able to solve that equation. I enter that on wolfram, it shows x as an ultra complex function of t containg strange things like the Airy bery function and stuff like $\pi^{16}$. SO this is definitely the wrong way.

So what approach should I use?

Answer (score 1):

Given that they ask for an answer up to two decimal places, they are definitely not asking you for a closed form solution, they want an approximation.

There are various methods to numerically approximate second order differential equations. (you're given initial values as well)

Try looking at these links:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FTCS_scheme
http://lpsa.swarthmore.edu/NumInt/NumIntIntro.html

These work by taking linear approximations of derivatives. Something like:

$$
\frac{x(t+h)-2x(t)+x(t-h)}{h^2}=x''(t)+O(h^2)
$$

Using an approximation like this, you get an expression of the form:

$$x_{t+1}=(2+3h^2t)x_t-x_{t-1}+h^2$$

Using a small value of $h$, you can approximate your final solution because you have the initial conditions, and you know how $x$ after the next timestep ($x_{t+1}$) is connected to the current ($x_t$) and the previous one ($x_{t-1}$). (iteration is the way to go)

Tedious to do by hand, so your best bet would be to write a small piece of code or to use something like wolfram.